# Report development, totalPages() Method

Tags: reporting, axapta, x++

Is it possible to reset the value returned by totalPages() method of reportRun class?

I have **one** report populated with **several** invoices, I want to reset the totalPages() value for each fetched invoice.

I tried to use element.reset() in the fetch() method of my report and it doesn't work, it splits my report by invoices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The `reset` method does the trick, but splits the report as you observed.

And unless your lines exactly fit one line there is no way to precalculate the value.